# Wait for busboy on#file to finish before calling on#finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, asynchronous

So okay I have this:

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    core.upload(filename, file, function(key2) {
        if (key2 != null) {
            key = key2;
        }
        console.log("KEY SET");
        file.resume();
    });
});
```

And a finish function:

```
req.busboy.on('finish', function () {
    console.log("FINISH FIRE");
}
```

The problem I am having that the `FINISH FIRE` fires first and only after the upload `KEY SET` fires and I cannot nest the functions as I set data in:

```
req.busboy.on('field', function (key, value, keyTruncated, valueTruncated) {
    //setting data
}
```

so having this:

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    core.upload(filename, file, function(key2) {
        if (key2 != null) {
            key = key2;
        }
        file.resume();
        runFinishFunction();
    });
});
```

Wouldn't really work, because I don't know if on#field has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function and variables like this

```
var finishOne, FinishTwo

finish(finish1, finish2) {
     if (finishOne != true && finish1 != null) finishOne = finish1;
     if (finishTwo != true && finish2 != null) finishTwo = finish2;
     if (finishOne && FinishTwo) {
         //RUN CODE
     }
}
```

And then you can have this in the methods and call one with:

```
finish(true, null) And the other one with finish(null, true)
```

It doesn't look like a good solution, so better solutions are welcome